# Color line by the highest point in gnuplot

Tags: colors, gnuplot, palette

Gnuplot script:

```
set palette defined (0 "blue", 100 "green", 500 "red")
splot "data" using 1:2:3 with lines lc palette z
```

Data file:

```
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 3 500
1 4 1
```

This results in something like this:

```
_/\
```

What I got, is that the 2 slopes are green.

I want them to be red. Or at least reddish.

I suspect that the coloring strategy is to use the color of the midpoint of the line.

How can I change the coloring strategy? ("color by highest point")

---

ALTERNATIVE:

If it is not possible this way, it would also be acceptable if it is done with another `linecolor` option. I have not quite figured it out yet, but I know there is direct coloring.

However, if possible I would prefer a palette-based solution, where I can easily generate a color gradient, and not have to do it manually in the datafile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Requires current gnuplot (version 5.4)**

Instead of coloring with `lc palette`, we will do our own lookup in the current palette to get an RGB value for that palette value and then tell the plot command to use that rgb value with `lc rgb variable`.

The `palette(cbvalue)` function is new in 5.4, which is why you need a current gnuplot.

Because we are no longer plotting referring to `lc palette` gnuplot does not autoscale or draw the colorbox by default, so we must explicitly give cbrange.

```
$DATA << EOD
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 3 500
1 4 1
EOD

set palette defined (0 "blue", 100 "green", 500 "red")
set cbrange [0:500]

highest(z) = (ztmp=zold,zold=z, ztmp>z ? ztmp : z)

zold = NaN
splot $DATA using 1:2:3:( palette(highest($3)) ) with lines lc rgb variable
```

[image]

To avoid having to reinitialize zold before a `replot`, you might want to include it in the plot statement as an in-line definition:

```
splot zold=NaN, $DATA using 1:2:3:( palette(highest($3)) ) with lines lc rgb variable
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Ethan's solution for gnuplot 5.4, here is a solution which works for gnuplot 5.0 and with minor modifications even with version 4.6. It uses the plotting style `with vectors`.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### apply linecolor from higher z-value
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1 1 1
1 2 1
1 3 500
1 4 1
EOD

set palette defined (0 "blue", 100 "green", 500 "red")
unset key

splot x1=y1=z1=NaN $Data u (x0=x1,x1=$1,x0):(y0=y1,y1=$2,y0):(z0=z1,z1=$3,z0):\
                   (x1-x0):(y1-y0):(z1-z0):(z0>z1 ? z0 : z1) w vec nohead palette
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]